# What name lookup rule apply to the name in the definition of static const data member

Tags: c++, class, static, member

There is a quote described name lookup applied to data member of a const static data member after the **quialified-id** of the data member:

**sec. 3.4.1/13:**

> A name used in the definition of a static data member of class X
>   (9.4.2) (after the qualified-id of the static member) is looked up as
>   if the name was used in a member function of X.

But we can define in-class static const data member:

```
class A
{
    static const int i = x;//x is a name defined an arbitrary const int
};
```

Rule from the sec. 3.4.1/13 does not apply to the name `x` lookup. **What rule will be applied actually? Please give a reference to a corresponding clause from standard.**

For instance, the following code is valid:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int a=5;
class A
{
public:
    static const int b=a;//b is unqualified-id of this data-member
};

int main(){ printf("%d\n",A::b); } //5
```

The following code is also valid:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    static const int a=7;
    static const int b=a;
};

int main(){ printf("%d\n",A::b); } //7
```

But the following is invalid:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    static const int b=a; //error: a was not declare in this scope.
    static const int a=7;
};

int main(){ printf("%d\n",A::b); }
```

It is unclear what rules applied to lookup of `a`.

Comment: Where is `x` defined in your case? Obviously it cannot be just *anywhere*.

Comment: I don't understand the question; the text you quote is saying that the lookup is the same as it would be for `void member() { x; }`  . Are you asking how names are looked up in member functions?

Comment: @Praetorian x defined somewhere. I would like to understood subsequent of the scope looked up the name x.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No. Quote said that this lookup the same for quailified-id. But what about lookup with unqualified id of static const data member?

Comment: It does not say "this lookup the same for qualified-id". It is talking about how `x` is looked up. The text in brackets is clarifying that it is talking about `x` and not `i`. "qualified-id" in this quote means `i`, and "name" means `x`

Comment: You're conflating the terms qualified and unqualified lookup with *qualified-id*. The latter, in this quote, is talking about the static data member identifier (`i`) which will need to be qualified with the class name (and namespace name) when you provide a definition - for instance, `const int NS::A::i;` - hence the phrase *qualified-id*. And §3.4.1/13 is saying that the rules listed under §3.4.1/8 will be used to lookup `x`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm confused by the text of the brackets. I thought that `after the qualified-id of the static member` means that this rule apply for the definition of static data member after qualified-id and doesn't apply to the definition after unqualified-id.

Comment: @Praetorian But if I provide an in-class definition like the `static const int i=x;` then the name x use in the definition after _unqulified-id_. But the text inside the brackets said that _after the qualified-id of the static member_. It is confused me. Can yoou clarify

Comment: There is no such thing as an in-class definition of static data member. That's a declaration with an initializer. A static data member definition **must be** provided outside the body of the class. Refer to 9.4.2/2. I don't know how to explain the qualified-id part any better than I did in my last comment.

Comment: Also, why are you so hung up on the name of the static data member itself? There's no name lookup happening there. The name lookup only applies to the name(s) in the initializer expression.

Comment: @Praetorian in C++11 in some circumstances you don't need the extra definition , that's not relevant to this question tho

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think that's limited to C++11. IIRC, you don't need the definition unless you odr-use the static data member. But you're right it's not relevant to this question.

Comment: @Praetorian I know what qualified-id does mean. It is specified in 5.1.1/8. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An in-class declaration of a static data member is not a definition even if it includes an initializer. Therefore §3.4.1/13 does not apply to your example.

Name lookup in class scope is defined by the rules of which scopes reach a class scope. §3.3.7/1.1:

> 1. The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration,
>      but also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>      exception-specifications, and brace-or-equal-initializers of
>      non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>      classes).
> 2. A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>      diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.
> 3. If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no
>      diagnostic is required.

The purpose of these rules is to allow a member function to access member variables that are declared later in the class. Because the rules don't mention initializers of static data members, name lookup from a static data member defaults to 3.4.1/7:

> A name used in the definition of a class X outside of a member
>   function body, default argument, exception- specification,
>   brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member, or nested
>   class definition shall be declared in one of the following ways:

The list essentially boils down to "a name must be a member of the same class, or declared in an enclosing scope." In your first example, `a` is declared in the enclosing namespace, so it is found. In the second example, `a` is declared before it is used.

But in the third example, it is used before it is declared which is illegal — and if there was a declaration of some `a` in the enclosing namespace, it would be undefined behavior due to 3.3.7/1.2.

Comment: So what rule will be applied to my examples? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int a=5;
class A
{
  public:
    static const int b=a; // The quote corresponds to the lookup for a.
                          // It says that the lookup logic for a is the same
                          // as the lookup for a name in a member function of A
};
```

If you have member function, let's make it `static` for easy comparison, let's see what the lookup for a name in the function looks like.

```
class A
{
  public:
    static void fun()
    {
       b = a;
       // The lookup for a:
       // 1. A local variable in the function.
       // 2. A `static` member of the class.
       // 3. A variable in the enclosing namespace.
    }

    static const int b;
};
```

When you use

```
    static const int b = a;
```

the lookup for `a` will be (2) and (3) from the function `foo` since `a` cannot be a local variable.